# Как написать сообщение на вотсап с сайта?

Tags: javascript, share, ya-share2

Здравствуйте! Хочу на сайте поставить кнопку Whatsapp, чтобы нажимая на нее в мобильной версии можно было написать сообщение на Whatsapp админа, при этом номер его телефона должен быть как бы вшит. Вот моя реализация и проблема:

http://kriskbx.github.io/whatsapp-sharing/ - тут генерируем код, указанный ниже:

```
<script type="text/javascript">if(typeof wabtn4fg==="undefined"){wabtn4fg=1;h=document.head||document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0],s=document.createElement("script");s.type="text/javascript";s.src="http://sibtrans.su/whatsapp-sharing/dist/whatsapp-button.js";h.appendChild(s);}</script>
<a href="intent://send/79133791044#Intent;scheme=smsto;package=com.whatsapp;action=android.intent.action.SENDTO;end">Whatsapp</a>
```

код ниже сделан по аналогии с инструкцией со страницы https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21500570/start-whatsapp-from-url-href-with-custom-text-content/ т.е.

```
href="intent://send/[countrycode_without_plus][number]#Intent;scheme=smsto;package=com.whatsapp;action=android.intent.action.SENDTO;end
```

Однако при открытии кнопки Whatsapp через мобильную версию сайта и при отправке сообщения в виде смс (такое ощущение, что смс отправляется не через Whatsapp, а просто через функцию смс телефона) подставляется по умолчанию в качестве адреса получателя номер `send/79133791044`

В этом и заключается ошибка, которую неизвестно как решить.